# VB6 - WinHttpRequest Timouts Problem

Tags: vb6, timeout, webrequest

I'm using a WebRequest in VB6 and I have the timeouts set at "5000" (5 seconds), but even after 5 seconds it is not timing out, any help is appreciated.

```
x:
Dim objWinHTTP
Set objWinHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")


    objWinHTTP.Open "POST", "http://twitter.com/" & TwitterUSERNAME
    objWinHTTP.SetTimeouts 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000


    Call objWinHTTP.Send(psData)
    MsgBox (objWinHTTP.Status)
    If objWinHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
    Timer.Enabled = False
    MsgBox ("D:")
    GoTo x
    End If
```

Comment: This isn't your problem... but don't use `GoTo`.  That went away with QBasic.  You might consider a `while` loop.

Comment: I've sorted that now, but I'm still not timing out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should set `objWinHTTP.SetTimeouts` before `objWinHTTP.Open`

and the four parameters you set for objWinHTTP.SetTimeouts are

```
Resolve, Connect, Send and Receive
```

So each value should be set according to that.